# Eclipse: Use user libraries from another project

Tags: java, eclipse, libraries

I have three Eclipse projects in my workspace. Two of them depend on the third one which contains common classes and libraries the other two both use:

```
project_X
  +src
project_Y
  +src
project_commons
  +src
  +lib
```

I can access and import all src classes from the commons project but the libraries are not found. Is there a way to automatically reference them in project_X and project_Y? If possible I'd like it that if I add a library to the commons project, the other two can automatically use it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to export those libraries on the common project:

`Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export`

Answer (score 0):

Make a Shared Library in you're Web-sphere console, with the path to where you have you're common classes, then include this shared library to any application you wish to share those classes to.

From you're Web-sphere Console, log in , then go to :
Environment-> shared Library's